# Backup Database and save to specific folder android

Tags: android, database-backups

I have a database and I want to back it up and restore it. I use this code to back up my database:

```
// Method To Backup Database//
public void OnClick_Backup(View v) {

    // Vibrates For 50 Mill//
    vibe.vibrate(50);

    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//jordanzimmittidevelopers.com.communityservicelogger//databases//community_service_Database";
            String backupDBPath = "Community Service Database";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup is successful to SD card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

It backs up the database fine but saves it to the root of the internal 
SD card. How can I get it to save the database to a new folder made by the aoo on the internal sd card. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code,

```
File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/newFolder");
if(!sd.exists()){
sd.mkdirs()
}
```

Code is create new folder if not exist. Then after copy database.